# Missing salesforce records while fetching from query_all method through python

Tags: python, salesforce, simple-salesforce

Data records are got missing while fetch from salesforce org i have used query,query_all,query_more,query_all_ittr method to fetch the data i am using python script for fetching the record pls help me got this issue
[output while running the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eM9GW.png) so total records are 11000 but i have got only 10998 records while running script

Comment: You should provide a code sample and detail what isn’t working and any errors you receive… show an example of what you recover versus what you expect to receive.

Comment: Could be connecting users not having rights to view all data, could be something about archived activities (what do you query, task/event)? What do you see with count / storage usage vs records retrieved.

Comment: i am trying to query id ,fields,permission read from a object like object permission  @eyescream   am not facing any error while running the script its not a python script issue

Comment: @Jarvis some records are python skipping while running the query methods total size of record is 11000 but i have got only 10998 records 2 records got skipped

Comment: -eyescream how to find those archived activities.